# Should a date in a REST-response be localized or more of a universal representation?

Tags: rest, date

REST is supposed to deliver readable information to the client. So for a single date (without the time portion) I would expect something similar to this:

`"birthday": "12th august 1980"` or maybe germanized `"12. August 1980"`

However this would cause trouble when sending the english representation back to the server with a german locale set. **So in the case of a date, wouldn't a more general representation be useful?** e.g. `1980-08-12` which could be transformed by the client application to regain readability.

Comment: While there's value to it, I don't thing that delivering human-readable content is a requirement of RESTful web services. So I wouldn't mind about the format, as long as it makes sense to the machines (programmers) that will consume it. Be general, or, I you really want it, change your format according to some headers. Nothing else is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the international representation of the date to avoid problems.

Comment: using yyyy-mm-dd now.